# When panel collapsed, getting rect of button no longer works

Tags: mfc, ribbon

I've tried this in several ways.  Deriving an object from CBCGPRibbonButton (same as CMFCRibbonButton) and using GetRect() from within the class, and having a click event find the button in the ribbon and get the rect.

What happens is that the rect is relative to the window that it is in.  But if the panel is collapsed, then the window it is in is not the ribbon bar so it gets the wrong location.

I need a way of getting the location relative to the ribbon bar.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I was trying to figure out what the rect was for the button:

[image]

When the panel had collapsed:

[image]

This is my solution:

```
class CMyButton : public CBCGPRibbonButton
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CHeaderFooter)

public:
    CMyButton()
    {
    };

    CMyButton(
        UINT    nID,
        LPCTSTR lpszText,
        int     nSmallImageIndex = -1,
        int     nLargeImageIndex = -1,
        BOOL    bAlwaysShowDescription = FALSE)
        : CBCGPRibbonButton(nID, lpszText, nSmallImageIndex, nLargeImageIndex, bAlwaysShowDescription)
    {
    }

    BOOL HasMenu() const override
    {
        return true;
    }

    CWnd* GetButtonWnd() const
    {
        CBCGPBaseRibbonElement* pDroppedDown = m_pParent->GetDroppedDown();
        CWnd* pWnd;
        if (pDroppedDown)  // Was popup opened from a collapsed panel from the ribbon?
        {
            pWnd = pDroppedDown->GetPopupMenu()->GetMenuBar();
        }
        else
        {
            pWnd = m_pParent->GetParentRibbonBar();
        }
        return pWnd;
    }

    void OnShowPopupMenu() override
    {
        CRect rect = GetRect();
        // pt is the bottom left corner of button relative to the window that
        // it is contained in.
        CPoint pt(rect.left, rect.bottom);
        GetButtonWnd()->ClientToScreen(&pt); // convert pt to screen coordinates

        ... // do other stuff with that point
    }
};

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CHeaderFooter, CBCGPRibbonButton)
```

which determines the CWnd that the button is part of so that the rect can be converted correctly to screen coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate in screen coords. 
Get the button rectangle from he ribbon. Use ClientToScreen and you have your screen coordinates now use your buttons parent handle with ScreenToClient and you have the cords relative to the ribbon bar.

PS: Even I don't know why to show a button when the ribbon is collapsed.

Comment: I already know to calc in screen coords.  I needed the window to do so.  Not the ribbon window, the dropdown.  I've figured it out now anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I don't understand what your PS means.